# Use Left Function To Static Character

Tags: function, ms-access-2010, trim

Is it possible to use the Left function, or another function if better suited, to left trim the values in a field up to a static character, in this case a dash? There is no set amount of characters leading up to the dash, so the length will be greater or smaller but will always have a dash in the field.

Here's an example of some values that could be in the field:

Test1 - Test1 description

Test1 Test2 - Test1 Test2 description

Test1 Test2 Test3 - Test1 Test2 Test3 description

Test4 - Test4 description

After the trim, the end result of record one would be Test1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mixture of Left or Mid and Instr.

```
 Left(Description,Instr(Description,"-")-1)
```

Where Description is the name of your field.

Comment: This trims everything from Left up to but not including the "-"? I could in theory use the Right function as well to trim up to the "-".

Comment: You must have tested before I added the -1, it trims the "-" as well.

Comment: I did...hahaha...so the -1 excludes the character you are searching for?

Comment: `Instr(..,"-")` is the position of "-", say 10, so `Instr(..,"-")-1` is just before "-", say 9, so you have `left(string,9)`

Comment: Got it...so I could use -2, which will take off the "-" and the space before the dash. Thanks!

Comment: Would the Right function work the same way? Just reverse and use Right?